# Mapping nested model objects in Sequel/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have an 'Orders' table in my database which contains columns for the orders's shipping address, e.g. `shipping_address_street` or `shipping_address_city` (legacy, so can't change). I would like to map these fields to a nested `Address` object that contains all the properties of the address.

```
Property order_number maps to column order_number
Property shipping_address contains an object of class `Address`
    Property shipping_address.street maps to column shipping_address_street
    Property shipping_address.city maps to column shipping_address_city
```

Is this supported by Sequel?

Answer (score 0):

Sequel supports this via the composition plugin: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/Composition.html